# Python multiprocessing pool.map with multiples arguments

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I need some help because I tried since two days, and I don't know how I can do this. I have function `compute_desc` that takes multiples arguments (5 to be exact) and I would like to run this in parallel.
I have this for now:

```
def compute_desc(coord, radius, coords, feat, verbose):
    # Compute here my descriptors
    return my_desc # numpy array (1x10 dimensions)

def main():
    points = np.rand.random((1000000, 4))
    coords = points[:, 0:3]
    feat = points[:, 3]
    all_features = np.empty((1000000, 10))
    all_features[:] = np.NAN
    scales = [0.5, 1, 2]
    for radius in scales:
        for index, coord in enumerate(coords):
            all_features[index, :] = compute_desc(coord,
                                                  radius,
                                                  coords,
                                                  feat,
                                                  False)
```

I would like to parallelize this. I saw several solutions with a Pool, but I don't understand how it works.

I tried with a `pool.map()`, but I can only send only one argument to the function.

Here is my solution (it doesn't work):

```
all_features = [pool.map(compute_desc, zip(point, repeat([radius, 
                                                          coords,
                                                          feat, 
                                                          False]
                                                         ) 
                                           ) 
                         )]
```

but I doubt it can work with a numpy array.

## EDIT

This is my minimum code with a pool (it works now):

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool
from itertools import repeat

def compute_desc(coord, radius, coords, feat, verbose):
    # Compute here my descriptors
    my_desc = np.rand.random((1, 10))
    return my_desc

def compute_desc_pool(args):
    coord, radius, coords, feat, verbose = args
    compute_desc(coord, radius, coords, feat, verbose)

def main():
    points = np.random.rand(1000000, 4)
    coords = points[:, 0:3]
    feat = points[:, 3]
    scales = [0.5, 1, 2]
    for radius in scales:
        with Pool() as pool:
            args = zip(points, repeat(radius),
                       repeat(coords),
                       repeat(feat),
                       repeat(kdtree),
                       repeat(False))
            feat_one_scale = pool.map(compute_desc_pool, args)

        feat_one_scale = np.array(feat_one_scale)
        if radius == scales[0]:
            all_features = feat_one_scale
        else: 
            all_features = np.hstack([all_features, feat_one_scale])

    # Others stuffs
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **generic solution** is to pass to `Pool.map` a *sequence of tuples*, each tuple holding one set of arguments for your worker function, and then to unpack the tuple in the worker function.

So, just change your function to accept only one argument, *a tuple of your arguments*, which you already prepared with `zip` and passed to `Pool.map`. Then simply unpack `args` to variables:

```
def compute_desc(args):
    coord, radius, coords, feat, verbose = args
    # Compute here my descriptors
```

Also, `Pool.map` should work with `numpy` types too, since after all, they are valid Python types.

Just be sure to properly `zip` 5 sequences, so your function receives a 5-tuple. You don't need to iterate over `point` in `coords`, `zip` will do that for you:

```
args = zip(coords, repeat(radius), repeat(coords), repeat(feat), repeat(False))
# args is a list of [(coords[0], radius, coords, feat, False), (coords[1], ... )]
```

(if you do, and give `point` as a first sequence to `zip`, the `zip` will iterate over that point, which is in this case a 3-element array).

Your `Pool.map` line should look like:

```
for radius in scales:
    args = zip(coords, repeat(radius), repeat(coords), repeat(feat), repeat(False))
    feat_one_scale = [pool.map(compute_desc_pool, args)]
    # other stuff
```

A solution **specific** to your case, where all arguments except one are fixed could be to use `functools.partial` (as the other answer suggests). Furthermore, you don't even need to unpack `coords` in the first argument, just pass the index `[0..n]` in `coords`, since each invocation of your worker function already receives the complete `coords` array.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work, I tried your solution with an intermediate function (I would like to keep my original function), but I have the following error: `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 6)`.

Comment: Please update your question with the exact code, so the error can be reproduced. And please write it so that anybody can copy/paste it and try it (without missing imports, etc). See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Excellent! So the problem was in your `zip` expression. Check my update.

Comment: it works now! But I'm a little bit surprised, I run this script on a server with 56 processes, I didn't expect my code run 56 time faster, but at least more than 3 times

Comment: and adding Pool(), I increase time of computing when I don't have much point (around 1000 by example)

Comment: I don't understand your question, if there is any.

Comment: more a remark than a question, I expected my code run more faster

Comment: Oh. Yes, you shouldn't expect to get speed-ups simply by distributing the load. In your case, there's probably a memory bottleneck since you copy huge amounts of data to each of the running instances. Also, see [Amdahl law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law). Try reducing the amount of data each worker has to receive, or try using a shared memory.

Comment: 1) the way you are using Pool waits for all results from all sub processes to finish before returning the final array, so you have to consider the wait-time. Consider using queues and post-process your results as they come in (if it fits your algorithm). 2). how large is `coords`? if it is large, you have to consider the time it took to spin up and load the subprocess with each `coords`.

Comment: 1) I'll see to use queue and process. I already test with these, but I didn't understand very well
2) It depends, it can be less of 1000 points, or more than 16 millions. It can be again more, because I can to have need to use 3 point clouds in same time

Answer (score 1):

I assume from your example that four of those five arguments would be constant to all calls to `compute_desc_pool`.  If so, then you can use `partial` to do this.

```
from functools import partial
....

def compute_desc_pool(coord, radius, coords, feat, verbose):    
    compute_desc(coord, radius, coords, feat, verbose)

def main():
    points = np.random.rand(1000000, 4)
    coords = points[:, 0:3]
    feat = points[:, 3]
    feat_one_scale = np.empty((1000000, 10))
    feat_one_scale[:] = np.NAN
    scales = [0.5, 1, 2]
    pool = Pool()
    for radius in scales:
        feat_one_scale = [pool.map(partial(compute_desc_pool, radius, coords, 
                                           feat, False), coords)]
```

Comment: In your example why define `compute_desc_pool`, when it takes the same arguments as `compute_desc`?

Comment: Because this was the structure of the original question. Of course it can be simplified. The question was clearly about passing static parameters alongside the mapped one when using `Pool.map()` and not about trivial simplifications to code provided only as an example.